# Remove/Delete from remote Media Library

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, media-player

I have a Media Center PC on my home network and I access the music library from my laptop through Windows Media 12 as a remote library.

I have assigned read/write permission to the library for the laptop on the PC itself, however from the laptop I am unable to remove or delete items from the library... basically there is no option to do so....

Have I missed something, or are you not allowed to delete from remote libraries?

Both machines are using Windows 7 with Media Player 12.

EDIT: I've tried Del and Backspace :)... the Delete option is not there when I right click like it is on the PC. I assume that means I'm missing an option or permission somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try rebuilding Media Player's database.

1. Exit Windows Media Player.
2. Click Start, click Run, type %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Media Player, and then click OK.
3. Select all the files in the folder, and then click Delete on the File menu.
     Note You do not have to delete the folders that are in this folder.
4. Restart Windows Media Player.

Note Windows Media Player automatically rebuilds the database.

If this does not resolve the problem, clear the Windows Media Player database cache files. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Exit Windows Media Player.
2. Click Start, click Run, type %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft, and then click OK.
3. Select the Media Player folder, and then click Delete on the File menu.
4. Restart Windows Media Player.

Comment: This is good, eventually brings back everything.

Answer (score 1):

> Have I missed something, or are you
>   not allowed to delete from remote
>   libraries?

Not through Windows Media Player I believe, It won't work for me either (just tried). I don't think Microsoft added a remote deletion feature through Windows Media Player itself, but you could set up a Windows share that you can access with all of your media to have finer control of your library remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user you remotely log in as have write-privileges to the folder you wish to delete?

(This is not the same as the share allowing write-permissions)

To set folder privileges, open folder properties, go to Security tab, then set permissions for the appropriate user. (Add "Everyone" and grant "Modify" permissions to grant delete permissions to all remote users).

Comment: Hmmm, just going to read up about HomeGroup permissioning. If I look at the security tab of the folder with the music in, the only location I can give users permission to is the Media Centre PC.

Comment: Still can't work this out, can't see a permission I've missed. I can delete and edit files in the Share folders containing the music but can't in the library through Media Player...

Comment: So your remote user can delete files on the windows share, but not via the Music Player software?